# When the protocol is https, Amazon S3 assets won't load, - Rails, Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I set up asset_sync gem on heroku, following this URL: https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync

The settings are working and I uploaded all the static assets at S3.

The problem is, when I open page through https protocol, can't access any of the assets, because the browser returns "This Connection is Untrusted". (same with Chrome & Firefox).

Every assets will be able to use after I admit access to s3 assets url. https://myapp.asset.s3.amazonaws.com/assets

Anyone had same problem? how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you checkout the SSL Support paragraph, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SSL certificate for s3 is a wildcard certificate, i.e. it is for *.s3.amazonaws.com. However a lot of certificate checking libraries define this to cover `foo.s3.amazonaws.com` but not `foo.bar.amazonaws.com`: wildcard certificates only go one level down.

The simplest solution is to pick a bucket name with no dots in it, e.g. `myapp-assets`.

Another solution is to access the files as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp.asset/assets/...`. I believe you'd have to set `config.assets.prefix` to tell rails that the assets aren't in the normal location relative to the asset host.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried the 1st solution and it's fixed.